# how to ignore HSTS on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, proxy, fiddler, hsts, mitmproxy

am running Firefox 91.11.0esr and intentionally [MITM'ing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) myself with [Fiddler Proxy](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), and it works on websites not using [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), but breaks on HSTS sites. How can i tell firefox to ignore HSTS? googling suggest going to about:settings and setting

```
security.mixed_content.use_hstsc=false
```

but that seems to make no difference. (perhaps an old config option which was removed/renamed at some point?)

[image]

related question: [how to ignore HSTS on Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1730252/how-to-ignore-hsts-on-chrome)

Comment: Why not just trust the Fiddler root certificate?

Comment: @DanielB i already tried that, and it does work on websites not using HSTS, but doesn't work on HSTS for some unknown reason. tried both the MakeCert and CertRoll certificate generators, same result on both :o

Comment: Delete the browser cache, that eliminates the saved HSTS settings.