# how to ignore HSTS on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, fiddler, hsts, mitmproxy

am running Chrome 103.0.5060.66 and intentionally [MITM'ing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) myself with [Fiddler Proxy](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), and it works on websites not using [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), but breaks on HSTS sites. How can i tell Chrome to ignore HSTS? example of a website using HSTS: https://www.century21.pt/ - example website -not- using HSTS: https://example.org - related question: [how to ignore HSTS on Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/1729832/how-to-ignore-hsts-on-firefox)

[image]

Comment: Clear the browser cache, then all HSTS pinnings are deleted. Afterwards make sure HSTS headers are stripped from the communication. AFAIR Fiddler does this by default, not sure about Mitmproxy.

Comment: Try typing `thisisunsafe` or `IknowwhatI'mdoing` while browsing that page.  The page at that point should reload and the website is displayed.  There is no way to NOT get that error website sine the host is configured for HSTS. This has in the past worked as recently as 1 year ago.  [The string has also changed over the years.](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/swarsy/did_you_know_that_you_can_type_this_is_unsafe_in/)

Comment: You can determine the current phrase by looking at the source code [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/components/security_interstitials/core/browser/resources/interstitial_large.js#19).  I am unable to look at the source code myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Chrome to ignore SSL warning on specific URLs?](https://superuser.com/questions/930329/how-to-configure-chrome-to-ignore-ssl-warning-on-specific-urls)

Comment: @Ramhound damn you're right! "thisisunsafe" lets me in! you should add that as an answer

Comment: @hanshenrik - There is already an existing question with an answer that suggests that solution. I try to avoid submitting a new answer when one already exists.

Comment: @Ramhound well i'm not convinced that "how to ignore HSTS *ERRORS*" is a duplicate of "how to ignore SSL *WARNINGS*", even though the solution is the same, and they're definitely related questions =/

Comment: It’s about the answer not the question. If the answer, answers your question, then it’s a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Per [RFC 6797](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6797), a browser that has a compliant implementation of [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) must not allow the feature to be disabled or bypassed. [Section 12.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6797#section-12.1) "No User Recourse" covers this topic:

> 12.1.  No User Recourse
>
> Failing secure connection establishment on any warnings or errors
> (per Section 8.4 ("Errors in Secure Transport Establishment")) should
> be done with "no user recourse".  This means that the user should not
> be presented with a dialog giving her the option to proceed.  Rather,
> it should be treated similarly to a server error where there is
> nothing further the user can do with respect to interacting with the
> target web application, other than wait and retry.
>
> Essentially, "any warnings or errors" means anything that would
> cause    the UA implementation to announce to the user that something
> is not    entirely correct with the connection establishment.
>
> Not doing this, i.e., allowing user recourse such as "clicking
> through warning/error dialogs", is a recipe for a man-in-the-middle
> attack.  If a web application issues an HSTS Policy, then it is
> implicitly opting into the "no user recourse" approach, whereby all
> certificate errors or warnings cause a connection termination, with
> no chance to "fool" users into making the wrong decision and
> compromising themselves.

Now of course, there is no requirement that a browser's developers fully conform to the RFC specification, such as the ["interstitial bypass keyword" in Ramhound's link](https://superuser.com/questions/930329/how-to-configure-chrome-to-ignore-ssl-warning-on-specific-urls), but the implementation may be unreliable and subject to change without notification, as some users on that link pointed out.

Comment: that explains why, it seems, older versions of firefox had a `security.mixed_content.use_hstsc=false` setting to ignore HSTS, but modern versions of firefox don't (afaik)

Comment: Indeed, though it appears that Mixed Content Usage for HSTS is addressed, but not fully defined in the RFC under section 12.4. 
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6797#section-12.4

Comment: dang, turns out Chrome does implement a bypass for this prompt, despite RFC6797. for more info see the comment of the top post =/

Comment: it says `giving her the option to proceed` meaning it is a limitation only for females, but Im a white male with a girlfriend, it should show me a dialog giving me option to proceed!